# Typing the select options manually or dynamically(php)

Tags: php, html

I have a form that using the post method and sends some information to my mysql db. One of the form components is the select tag with predictable options. Should I type them manually in html or grab them from a mysql using php.

Security and efficiency are what I care about, or should I be aware to something else?

Comment: There are no security issues if you protect your submissions server-side properly. And the only efficiency you'll get is the time saved from typing the select options.

Comment: Depends on how your code is there could be mysql injection, insertion of different data if the users wants to, so if you want to make sure the data is correct check it back, use prepared statements, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never type them.**

- Even if they are **static**, just use PHP arrays to generate them.
- If they are **dynamic**, use PHP DB queries to generate them.

Dynamic generation allows you to easily alter their looks later on. While hardcoding them *(typing)* will make your life much more complicated if things change in the future.